Sefton and Scowcroft paper on understanding marginal contribution to active risk
I am looking to obtain a link or citation to the paper 'understanding marginal contribution to active risk' by Sefton and Scowcroft. I believe it was document compiled by ubs research and MSCI and dealt with looking to define MCER via MCAR. Would anyone have a link to this paper?

Perhaps this old chap can help you find his paper https://profiles.imperial.ac.uk/j.sefton

@nbbo2 Thanks very much! Appreciate it.
